# Access directly class attribute through class instance Python

Tags: python, oop

Let's assume that we have the following class

```
class Imageset():
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.frames = self.read_frames(path)

    def read_frames(self, path):
        toret = []
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
        # Check if video opened successfully
        if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
            print("Error opening video file")
        # Read until video is completed
        while(cap.isOpened()):
            # Capture frame-by-frame
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                # Store frame to array
                toret.append(frame)
            # No more frames to read, break the loop
            else:
                break
        # When everything done, release the video capture object
        cap.release()

        return np.array(toret)
```

Then we want to do the following

```
frames = Imageset('video-crop.mp4')
print(frames.shape)
```

As it is, it displays an error stating that shape is not a known attribute. How could we modify this behavior to automatically handle the Numpy array (the `self.frames` attribute) when accessing attributes of the `Imageset` class?

Comment: The problem here is that `self.read_frames(path)` is saved to `self.frames`, so the attributes of Numpy array should be taken here. Try `print(frames.frames.shape)`

Comment: How should implement it then to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: In your case i don't see a reason/use-case for using a class at all. Maybe, all you need is a single function `read_frames(path)` to convert `path` to Numpy array of frames.

Comment: The example posted here is just for illustration purposes. I would like to add some attributes to this image set such as: width, height and number of frames. Also, I would like to perform operations along frames such as cropping or slicing. Do you think there is a better way to do it knowing all that extra info?

Comment: In such case, you shouldn't call `Imageset` object "frames". Maybe, "video" would suit better. It would be logical for a video to have width, height, number of frames and a Numpy array of frames and would help you avoid confusion. To work with the frames of the video, you would use something like `video.frames.shape`, which seems reasonable.

Comment: Another solution would be to make `Imageset` a subclass of numpy array, which would allow you to use Numpy stuff directly on your `Imageset` object, but you will be limited in the choice of names, as the namespace will already include things from the array itself. You can redefine them, but still need to keep track of them to do so.